# swift Regular Expression and (.*?)

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I want to extract substrings from a string that match a regex pattern.

The problem is this code : `("ytplayer.config = {(.*?)};").exec(responseStringC)`. It must match but return  nil.

string.exec function :

```
extension String {
    func exec (str: String) -> Array<String> {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: self, options: [.CaseInsensitive,.IgnoreMetacharacters])
            let nsstr = str as NSString
            let all = NSRange(location: 0, length: nsstr.length)
            var matches : Array<String> = Array<String>()
            regex.enumerateMatchesInString(str, options:  NSMatchingOptions(rawValue: 0), range: all) {
                (result : NSTextCheckingResult?, _, _) in
                let theResult = nsstr.substringWithRange(result!.range)
                matches.append(theResult)
            }
            return matches
        } catch {
            print("error")
            return Array<String>()
        }
    }
}
```

"responseStringC" variable is :

http://pastebin.com/uvvq9ULA

the problem is return nil. Any Clue?

Comment: I can't even figure out what the question is here.

Comment: What is your problem? Is there an error during compiling or when running your app?

Comment: return nil. not match.

Comment: I suggest adding `(?s)` and escaping the dot - `"(?s)ytplayer\\.config = {(.*?)};"` - and remove `.IgnoreMetacharacters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `exec` code contains [`.IgnoreMetacharacters` flag](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsregularexpressionoptions/1407714-ignoremetacharacters):

> Treat the entire pattern as a literal string.

Remove it so that the pattern could be treated as a regex pattern.

Also, a good idea is to use a DOTALL modifier `(?s)` at the start of the pattern.

Also, remember that a dot matches any character, escape it to match a literal dot.

As for the pattern, I'd recommend

```
"(?s)ytplayer\\.config = \\{(.*?)\\};"
```

Or a much faster:

```
"(?s)ytplayer\\.config = \\{([^}]*(?:\\}(?!;)[^}]*)*)\\};"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS2wP6/1)

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot about escaping. Updated.